# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined using Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a Node.js API, however every time I try to create a new user in my database using Sequelize I get the following error:
[Error Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twOjh.png)

Here is my User.js model:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

Here is my UserController.js

```
const { User } = require('../models/User');

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {
        const user = await User.create(req.body);

        res.json(user);
    }
}
```

My index.js for the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');

require('../src/models/index');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

The index.js for the model configuration

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/database.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

My routes.js file:

```
const { Router } = require('express');

const UserController = require('./controllers/UserController');

const routes = Router();

routes.post("/users", UserController.store);

module.exports = routes;
```

It is a pretty simple project however this error is making me go crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered what was wrong, the thing was that my index.js for the model folder, was wrong. In the end the following line `const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/database.js')[env];` was giving me the error. I just ajusted the require so that my configurations could be found, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your import and export don't match.

You import like this:

```
const { User } = require('../models/User');
```

But, you export a function that must be called:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

So, when you do this:

```
const { User } = require('../models/User');
```

There is no `.User` property exported so you get `undefined`.

It looks like you need to change the import to be like this:

```
const User = require('../models/User')(sequelize, DataTypes);
```